# problem while delete the node on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

i have read value from database "mycart" and using loop to set value from mycart to the "purchase history" database. After finish the set the value to purchase history i want delete data from table mycart. i have try to delete data from mycart table but its pop up error.

```
var ref=database.ref("mycart/"+uid);
ref.on('value',gotData,errData);
-----

  function gotData(data){
    var id=data.val();
    var keys=Object.keys(id);
    var today = new Date();    
    for(let i = 0; i<keys.length;i++){
        var k =keys[i]; 

       firebase.database().ref('purchaseHistory/'+uid).push().set({
          historyid: id[k].uid,
          imageUrl: id[k].image,
          packagePlace: id[k].packageplace,
          price: id[k].price,
          quantity: id[k].quantity,
          time: isoDate

        }).then(()=>{

          $.getScript("../controler/emailnotification.js", function(){});

});

  }
ref.remove();
}
```

Comment: you are looping asynchronous code. the problem could be code is still running while and you are removing the ref

Comment: is data.val() synchronous ?

Comment: im still looking for method to call back, after looping is done and there where i should remove it, but i don't know how to do it